# How can I get a list of attributes of a Python object which doen't have __dict__?

Tags: python, attributes, inspect

How would you do this for an instance of [`xml.etree.cElementTree.Element`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects)?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
>>> from xml.etree.cElementTree import Element 
>>> obj = Element('aaa')
>>> obj
<Element 'aaa' at 0x101bde270>
>>> dir(obj)
['__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__reduce__', 'append', 'clear', 'extend', 'find', 'findall', 'findtext', 'get', 'getchildren', 'getiterator', 'insert', 'items', 'iter', 'iterfind', 'itertext', 'keys', 'makeelement', 'remove', 'set']
>>> obj.tag
'aaa'
```

Comment: I am just used to Ruby simplicity in this respect and expect that it must be possible in Python as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If attributes are returned via custom `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`, you cannot know whether an attribute will be returned without trying and you cannot get a full list without trying all possible names. You can get the list of static attributes via [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir).

Comment: `>>> Element('aaa').__getattr__` results in `AttributeError: __getattr__`

Comment: Because this class doesn't have this method. First I thought you are asking about dynamic attributes but Element is a common class with working `dir()`.

Comment: `dir()` doesn't provide all attributes, so I wonder how I can get a full list.

Comment: No, `tag` exists in `dir()`. Please provide examples of non-working code.

Comment: Probably it is not `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`, as it is not clear from your code. My `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` has much longer `dir()`. Also, are you sure your `obj` really has the `tag` attribute?

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right, it was `xml.etree.cElementTree.Element`. I have corrected my question. The instance does have `tag` attribute, which is not in the list given by `dir()`

Answer (score 1):

The `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` object does have a `__dict__`.

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element  
>>> obj = Element('aaa')
>>> obj.__dict__
{'attrib': {}, 'tag': 'aaa', '_children': []}
```

The `__dict__` is the dictionary of currently defined attributes. `dir()` calls `__dir__()`, which may be overrided.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect question. `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` does have a `__dict__`, however `xml.etree.cElementTree.Element` doesn't. In case of the latest, how would you get all attributes?

Comment: `xml.etree.cElementTree.Element` is implemented as a C Library. Since the `tags` attribute is not made available to you, it doesn't show up for you under `dir()`. If you want to use introspection, use the Python version `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`.

Comment: So there is no way I can get the full list of attributes for such object?